# Multi deep learning frameworks running on one GPU causes CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

I want to run Caffe and TensorFlow  (only evaluation) in one c++ project but causes error as title mentioned. For some reasons I can not retrain the Caffe model to TensorFlow or the other way around. To my knowledge this error means GPU is busy and only provides service for one framework. Any thing I can do?

I have two init functions to load the Caffe and TF model and two predict functions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've solved it. My Caffe and TF both use cuDNN which seems only allow one framwork(or instance?) running on one GPU. I just turn off the Caffe's cuDNN and it works.